# Photoshop CS6 - Is there anyway to apply gradient overlay on multiple layers at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gradient, overlay

Is there some way that I don't have to go to one layer by one and open their layer style one by one?? I wanna be able to apply the dither option of the gradient overlay for every layer style. Is that possible? I'm not sure if I explained it correctly but does anyone know how to do it??

Comment: Hey sam, can you add a screenshot or two of what you've got so far? It might help to be able to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the layer styles or apply a layer for some effect? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a possibility to change the layer of multiple layers at once. There are, however, two possible workarounds:

1. Place the layers you want to affect into a folder, and change the *folder's* Layer Style.
2. Change the Layer Style of one layer the way you want it, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> and drag the 'fx' icon from one layer entry in the Layers pallette to every other layer you want to affect.

Comment: Never knew you could drag the 'fx' icon!

Comment: @Cai Just like you can drag or Alt-drag a layer mask. Don't tell me you didn't know that either! :P

Comment: haha... um yes i knew that. Honestly